# Database Mail not sending

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to send email using the DatabaseMail on SQL Server 2008; I can see my emails sitting in the `msdb.dbo.sysmail_unsentitems`

But they just sit there and I get no error messages. 
I've checked and I have rights to use the DatabaseMail by using the following:

```
EXEC msdb.sys.sp_helprolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole';
```

And I tried running

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sysmail_help_queue_sp @queue_type = 'mail';
```

which shows the length as the number of emails I've tried to send, but the Status is showing as Inactive.

Am I missing something else?

Comment: In SSMS, expand the "Management" icon/folder, right-click "Database Mail" and select "View Database Mail Log".  Do you see any errors there?

Comment: No Errors in the log.

Comment: A couple of things to try/check:  1.  Make sure the database owner of [msdb] is [sa].  2. Restart SQL Agent and try a test email.  3. Check with your network/system admin to see if ports are blocked.  4. Sometimes simply restarting the SQL service works too. (Obviously, if it's a production system, you'll have to find an appropriate time to do this.)

Comment: The solution for me was to:

>     Open SQL Server Configuration Manager
>     Select SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)
>     Log on as: This was set to Local System 
>     on changing it to Network Source the emails now get sent.

Can someone explain why this is the case, I tried changing back to Local System and it ceases to work again.